# 3D Clusplot in R increase components explain

Tags: r, clustering, data-visualization

I used the clusplot function with my data and got this:

f[image] two components explain 3.15% of the point variability

The graph seems fine but the "two components explain 3.15% of the point variability" seems pretty small, I was wondering how can I increase the point variability, should I used a third component? If yes how can I create a 3D clusplot in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume data name is df and we just so happens to want 4 clusters

```
library(rgl)

kdf<- kmeans(df,4)# Create kmeans clustering
newdf <- data.frame(df, K=kdf$cluster)#Include the number of cluster in the data set
pcdf <- princomp(df,cor=T,score=T)
summary(pcdf)#Compute the validity of each component/dimension
plot3d(pcdf$scores, col=newdf$K)#Create a 3D plot
```

My 3D plot looks like this:

[image: 3D Plot of df]